# Iterate through tuples in list and get its value

Tags: list, erlang, tuples

I have a list like this and i would like to find the word fruit and extract "Apple" and {"1"}. The list can be of varying size.

List = [{{"1"},{fruit,"Apple"}},{{"2"},unknown},{{"3"},{vegetable,"Potato"}}]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should read some basic Erlang book to start. for example [LearnYouSomeErlang](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/content).

Your problem is often solved using pattern matching in a list comprehension, here is an example directly in the shell:

```
1> List = [{{"1"},{fruit,"Apple"}},{{"2"},unknown},{{"3"},{vegetable,"Potato"}}].
[{{"1"},{fruit,"Apple"}},
 {{"2"},unknown},
 {{"3"},{vegetable,"Potato"}}]
2> [{Fruit,Qty} || {{Qty},{fruit,Fruit}} <- List ].
[{"Apple","1"}]
3>
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses several function clauses instead of a list comprehension:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).


get_list() ->
[
    {{"1"},{fruit,"Apple"}},
    {{"2"},unknown},
    {{"3"},{vegetable,"Potato"}},
    {{"2"},{fruit,"Banana"}}
].


process_list([]) ->
    [];
process_list([ {{N}, {fruit, Fruit}} | Tail]) ->
    [{N, Fruit} | process_list(Tail) ];
process_list([_Head | Tail]) ->
    process_list(Tail).
```

In the shell:

```
7> c(my).                            
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

8> my:process_list(my:get_list()).
[{"1","Apple"},{"2","Banana"}]
```

The second function clause tries to match a tuple at the head of the list containing the atom `fruit`.  If the head of the list is a tuple containing `fruit`, then the quantity and the type of the fruit is added to a results list.

If the second function clause doesn't match, i.e. the head of the list is a tuple that does not contain the atom `fruit`, then the third function clause will match, and it discards the head of the list.

Finally, when you get to the end of the list, the first function clause will match, and it returns the empty list, which neatly gets `cons'ed` to the end of the result list, making it a *proper list*.

Another way to solve the problem is to introduce an *accumulator* to gather the results:

```
process_list(L) ->
    process_list(L, []).  %The empty list for the second argument is the accumulator.

process_list([], Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc);
process_list([ {{N}, {fruit, Fruit}} | Tail], Acc) ->
    process_list(Tail, [ {N,Fruit} | Acc ]);  %Add the match to the accumulator.
process_list([_Head | Tail], Acc) ->
    process_list(Tail, Acc).
```

As you can see in Pascal's example, Erlang's list comprehensions can accomplish the same thing in a very brief amount of code.